# How to remove sqlite.net.platform.xamarinandroid from xamarin android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to work on sqlite related operation's on my android project but in latest android version's getting fallowing exception i.e system/lib/libsqlite.so. Most of the post suggest to remove all sqlite pcl related packages and install latest sqlite.net.xamarinandroidN package. After installing they are mentioned remove old sqlite.net.platform.xamarinandroid dll but I am unable to remove that. I have go to my project references and unselect the xamarinandroid.dll and clean and rebuild then it's dll again added to the project automatically. Most of are mentioned that after removing that old dll only the newly installed sqlite is worked. Please suggest how can I remove old sqlite. I am using sqlite.net.xamarinandroidn and sqlite.net.pcl-async packages in my project.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the package from your project's NuGet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project.
2. Click on "Manage NuGet packages"
3. Open the "Installed" tab.
4. Hover over the package you want to uninstall, then click on the red X or you can click the Uninstall button that should be displayed on the Right.

I suggest deleting all the SQLite packages, then reinstall the ones you need.

**And a tip:**

This is the package you want to add (I found this in assembly references):
[image: This is the package you want to add]

This is what the package will look like in your projects References once added:
[image: This is what the "System.Data.SQLite" packages will look like once added to your references.]

Then these ones you can add through the NuGet Package Manager:
[image]